# Symfony3 cache (Warning: rename) after update

Tags: php, caching, warnings, symfony

I have problem, after insert or update in my screen i see message:

> Warning:
>   rename(C:\Users\Name\Desktop\BaseApp\var\cache\dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies__CG__AppBundleEntityCategory.php.57483ae07bdb29.50220410,C:\Users\Name\Desktop\BaseApp\var\cache\dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies__CG__AppBundleEntityCategory.php):

All time after update i see this message, after reload page all is right,
i use my app on windows, dev mode, symfony3,

Regards!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that the Doctrine's proxy class generation code doesn't handle concurrent requests very well. It works on Unix-like systems, but not on Windows, where you can't just rename over a file that is open.

See [configuration of the doctrine bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html). You'll most like have `auto_generate_proxy_classes` set to `"%kernel.debug%"` (this is the default setting in symfony standard edition).

Try changing `auto_generate_proxy_classes` to `false`. You'll now have to manually clear the cache if you change your entities, but that error should be gone.

Comment: Thanks so much you saved my day!

Comment: I know this question is old. So, Doctrine only rename the file on *dev* mode? So if I'm in production it wont regenerate the file as the cache does not recreate in production mode?

Comment: Yes, if you have `auto_generate_proxy_classes` set to `%kernel.debug%`, then it will be regenerated only in dev mode. In production, they will be generated only once during cache warmup.